# Select multiple ranges on filter slider - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to implement multiple range selections on tableau filter sliders. Refer to the picture below

[image]

In this case if i need to select values falling in range between 1 and 5 and again between 10 and 15, how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Parameters. Create 4 Integer parameters then create a calculated field to filter.

Using Superstore data I created the following filter calc and selected True.

```
(sum([Sales]) > [range 1 start]
and 
sum([Sales]) < [range 1 end])
or
(sum([Sales]) > [range 2 start]
and 
SUM([Sales]) < [range 2 end])
```

[image]